# Can't load page in Spring MVC

Tags: java, spring, jsp, spring-mvc

I want to add a page in my spring MVC. I can call the index file but I can't click on the link in `index.jsp` to show page `product.jsp`. Its error message is "The requested resource is not available".

Below is my controller code:

```
@RequestMapping({"/", "/index"})
public String index(ModelMap model, HttpSession session, Principal principal) throws Exception {
    return "index";
}

@RequestMapping({"/product"})
public String product(ModelMap model, HttpSession session, Principal principal) throws Exception {
    return "product";
}
```

this index.jsp

```
<div class="row">
   <div class="col-sm-4 menu-img-pad">
       <ul class="multi-column-dropdown">
          <li><a href="../product.jsp">Joggers</a></li>
          <li><a href="../product.jsp">Foot Ball</a></li>
          <li><a href="../product.jsp">Cricket</a></li>
       </ul>
   </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Try this: `<a href="/product">Joggers</a>`

Comment: provide the absolute path for product.jsp or keep both the file(index.jsp and product.jsp ) in the same folder.

Comment: @Aamir  >Folder>index.jsp and product is in the same position like Folder.

Comment: @Càphêđen it not works.

Answer (score 0):

You need to define a ViewResolver in order to let spring how to find your views.

Have a look [here](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/mvc.html#mvc-viewresolver). In your case an [InternalResourceViewResolver](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/servlet/view/InternalResourceViewResolver.html) would work.

An then -- in order to call your handler -- your link should look point to `/product` as you defined the path in your `@RequestMapping` method

Answer (score 0):

Add below configuration to dispatcher-servlet.xml

```
<bean
    class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
    <property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/views/" />
    <property name="suffix" value=".jsp" />
</bean>
```

In above configuration,views is folder name where container will look for your product.jsp file